# Constructing a class via references to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I'm trying to understand the constructor used in a class implemented in a library I am using. The key components of class SequenceAnalyzer look like:

```
class SequenceAnalyzer {
  protected:
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images_;

  public:
    SequenceAnalyzer( std::vector<cv::Mat> *images = NULL )
    {
        if (images != NULL)
          images_ = (*images);
    }

};
```

When constructing an instance of this class in my main, I pass it a reference to a vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> myImages;
SequenceAnalyzer se(&myImages);
```

Now passing in my images by reference passed their location in memory to the class. But my understanding of the (*images) operator means that their address has been dereferenced and so the = operator then copies the contents.

Is there any advantage in passing myImages into the class in this manner? Why are pointers used in the first place if it doesn't end in saved copying overhead anyway?

Comment: I don't see any references here.

Comment: If you mean the difference between references and pointers than I'm afraid that's a hazy subject for me. If you mean which library am I talking about, it's the [OpenCV Structure from Motion library project](http://code.google.com/p/gsoc2011sfm/).

Comment: You are passing it as pointer to the `vector<cv::Mat>` object myImages.

Comment: @Chris: The former, and I can tell. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any advantage. I would write the same code as:

```
SequenceAnalyzer( const std::vector<cv::Mat>& images = std::vector<cv::Mat>()) :
    images_(images)
{
}
```

Now I don't need to worry about pointers:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> myImages;
SequenceAnalyzer se(myImages);
```

Comment: I think he's asking about passing by reference-_or_-pointer _vs_ by value, not between the two.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: maybe, but it's unclear from the question.

Comment: As for reference vs pointer, my impression was that C++ tended to prefer using references in function definitions, rather than pointers, but that's just my impression. The code above certainly looks a more attractive option than the original.

Comment: "if it doesn't end in saving copying overhead anyway" I think it's clear he wants to compare something that copies with something that doesn't.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: If the question is about by pointer vs by value, then pointers *do* save a copy and then the question quoted by you is not applicable. So I conclude the question is about pointers vs references, or even more likely the OP doesn't know himself.

Comment: @ybungalobill: "If the question is about by pointer vs by value, then pointers _do_ save a copy" Yes, and that is the answer to this question; the OP clearly forgot about the second copy and is trying to figure out why you'd need pointers to do that saving of a copy, rather than just passing by value in the first place. Trying to reason about what the question means by assuming the OP knows the answer to it is silly!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: OK, so the OP cannot formulate the question unambiguously. Now, what do you want me to do?

Comment: Seems I've opened a can of worms! I understand the idea of by-reference rather than by-value meaning that data is only copied when needed. What I was confused by was the way it was actually set out in the code, but I now understand what's going on - thanks!

Comment: @ybungalobill: I was hoping you'd change "there isn't any advantage [compared to what?!]" to "there is most definitely an advantage [compared to passing by value]" to make your answer correct. But I'll give up now!

Answer (score 1):

> When constructing an instance of this class in my main, I pass it a
>   reference to a vector:
>
> ```
> std::vector<cv::Mat> myImages;
> SequenceAnalyzer se(&myImages);
> ```

No, you don't.

`&` on a type indicates a reference type; `&` on an expression is the "address-of" operator and yields a pointer! That's why your constructor accepts a pointer, otherwise this would not work.

> Now passing in my images by <strike>reference</strike> *[pointer]* passed their location in memory
>   to the class. But my understanding of the `(*images)` operator means
>   that their address has been dereferenced and so the `=` operator then
>   copies the contents.

Correct.

> Is there any advantage in passing myImages into the class in this
>   manner? Why are pointers used in the first place if it doesn't end in
>   saved copying overhead anyway?

Presumably the programmer wanted to avoid the vector being copied *twice* (once for the argument and again for storage as a member). It's unusual to do that with a pointer rather than a reference, though.

---

I would have instead written:

```
class SequenceAnalyzer {
  protected:
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images_;

  public:
    SequenceAnalyzer(const std::vector<cv::Mat>& images = std::vector<cv::Mat>())
       : images_(images) {};
};
```

Now you have your reference parameter, your default, and also you're initialising properly.

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameter by pointer (or reference) instead of by value avoid temporary copy. So copy is done only when needed, and not when passing it as a parameter. Another advantage  is that you can have a NULL default parameter, without creating a default constructor. In this case the implicit default constructor should do the same.

A more elegant way can be this:

```
SequenceAnalyzer(const std::vector<cv::Mat>& images) {
  images_ = images;
}
```

No temporary copy (you're passing by reference) and who uses this is sure images wont be modified.

Comment: however, the way they do that in the original post is really bad c++ style :)

Comment: You can have a default parameter with the reference way, too.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal yes, but it have to be an instantiated object.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: If you mean _previously_ instantiated then, no, it doesn't.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I mean it have to be previously instantiated (like a static variable) or temporary instantiated.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: Right, just like any other default function parameter. Your answer implies that there's some magical difference with refs-to-const which prevents being able to use a default parameter, and your comments are now out of sync with that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be of some help to know that even if you copy the vector, you will copy only the image headers (structure containing type, width, height, etc). Mat objects encapsulate a smart pointer to the data, so a deep copy of the image data happens only when calling specific functions (Mat::copyTo(), Mat::clone())